# How to use choice() method in groovy?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Sorry for the noob question. I'm new to Groovy.

I'm debugging some Jenkins scripts with the groovysh utility.
Here is a snippet of code:

```
println("Start")

List job_params() {
    def parameter_list = [
            choice(name: 'BAUDRATE',
                choices: ['9600', '115200'],
                description: 'Baud rate of the device.'),
        ]

    return parameters(parameter_list)
}

params = job_params()

println("End")
```

When I try to run this code I receive error message:

```
groovy:000> :load BExample.gvy
Start
===> null
===> true
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.choice() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[name:BAUDRATE, choices:[9600, 115200], description:Baud rate of the device.]]
Possible solutions: collect()
        at groovysh_evaluate.job_params (groovysh_evaluate:6)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Do I need to "import" something?
How can I fix this problem.

BTW, this code snippet works on Jenkins without error.

Comment: Jenkins has its own Domain Specific Language (DSL) developed in Groovy which is used as a script. You can't use this DSL syntax in standalone Groovy script. If you want to use the same you need to get the DSL library in your Groovy engine.

Comment: @HiteshA.Bosamiya Can you please clarify is it somehow possible to "groovysh" some script with DSL support? Do I need to install some additional package or so?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above under comments, you may like to refer to https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/User-Power-Moves.md to run your DSL locally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found that the "jenkinsci / job-dsl-plugin" was forked from "JavaPosseRoundup/job-dsl-plugin". Shouldn't we use original "JavaPosseRoundup/job-dsl-plugin" instead?

Comment: Now I see, that "JavaPosseRoundup/job-dsl-plugin" was deprecated.

Comment: However, I couldn't execute the script given via original question :(